# Invalid use of non-static data member while using templates

Tags: c++, templates, default-arguments

I have the following code snipped, which implements a Binary Search Tree with templates:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Node{
    public:
    T data;
    Node<T> *left;
    Node<T> *right;
    Node<T> *parent;

    Node(T input_data=NULL){
        data=input_data;
        left=NULL;
        right=NULL;
        parent =NULL;    
    }
};



template<typename T>
class BinarySearchTree{
    private:
    long n;
    Node<T> *root;


    public:
    BinarySearchTree(Node<T> *input_root=NULL, long input_size=0){
        n=input_size;
        root=input_root;
    } 

    void insert(Node<T> *p=root, T  data){
        Node<T> *par=NULL;
        while(p!=NULL){
            par=p;
            if(data <= p->data)
                p=p->left;
            else 
                p=p->right;
        }
        Node<T> *z=new Node<T>(data);
        if(root==NULL){
            root=z;
            n=1;
            return;
        }
        z->parent=par;
        if(data<=par->data)
            par->left=z;
        else
            par->right=z;

        n+=1;                
    }

    void inorder(Node<T> *p=root){
        if(p){
            inorder(p->left);
            cout<<p->data<<" ";
            inorder(p->right);
        }
    }

int main(){
    BinarySearchTree<int> *t=new BinarySearchTree<int>();
    t->insert(5);
    t->insert(15);
    t->insert(3);
    t->insert(14);
    t->insert(25);
    t->insert(10);
    t->inorder();

}
```

There's a compilation error on line 27, (i.e. Node *root;), and which reads: "Invalid use of non-static data member 'BinarySearchTree::root'". I think it has to do with the default arguments that I've included have in the functions 'insert' and 'inorder', because I don't get the error when I remove the default argument 'root'.

My question is, what is happening and how do I get around it? I would like to preserve the default argument of root if that's possible.

If it matters, I'm using a software called '[Quincy 2005](http://www.codecutter.net/tools/quincy/)' on Windows 8.1 to compile (for certain reasons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default value must be a literal, not a variable name.

Additionally, arguments with default values must come last in the argument list.

Rather use:

```
void insert(Node<T> *p, T data) { ... }

// overload with only one argument
void insert(T data)
{
    insert(root, data)
}
```

Comment: "A default value must be a literal" I think this is not true. From the standard : "int g(int x = f(a)); // default argument: f(::a)" .f(a) is clearly not a literal.

Comment: Default values must come last (+1), but default values do not have to be literals (-1). They just can't be non-static data members.

Comment: @Barry but my Node<T> *root; is non-static. What's happening?

Comment: @abhidivekar Exactly. Default argument can't be a non-static data member. `root` is a non-static data member.

Comment: @Barry: okay I got it. The wording just confused me for a second :p

Answer (score 0):

In a line such as

```
void insert( Node<T>* p = root ,T data ) {...}
```

there are 2 errors.

Firstly ,you can only use default value for the arguments starting at the last parameter and backwards.
Since you didn't give data a default value ,this is an error (solution reorder parameters ,those without default must come first).

Secondly ,the value `root` is a member of `this` and there is no `this` at the point of declaration.
Solution if you need a default there use **`nullptr`** as the default and inside your function test for **`nullptr`** and if so use `root` instead.

Comment: Yeah I did that in the final implementation of the code. It worked perfectly, but I was curious as to what is the theory behind this.